# Why should i explicitly cast hex value to byte when using ternary operator?

Tags: c#, casting, hex, byte, ternary-operator

For example:

```
byte a = 0x01; // Works fine
byte b = foo() ? 0x01 : 0x02; // Get error "Cannot impicitly convert int to byte"
```

Why it so?

Comment: @JonasW This is not quite a duplicate, because OP knows that the cast can fix the second line in his code snippet; he is not sure why the cast isn't required on the first line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you assign a numeric literal (it does not matter if it is hex or decimal) to a variable of type `byte`, the compiler checks that the value fits in a `byte`. Once the compiler knows that the value fits, it treats the literal as if it were of type `byte`, matching the type of the variable.

When you use a ternary expression, however, the compiler is no longer sure what is going to be the value of the expression. By default it treats the values inside the conditional expression as integer literals, because there is no type conversion. What the compiler sees, therefore, is an assignment of a non-constant `int` expression to a variable of type `byte`. This triggers the error that you are seeing.

Comment: Odd behavior, cause i'm trying to assign constant value, i mean why compiler can't figure that 0x01 and 0x02 can fit into byte?

Comment: @ArtemSokolov is it shadowed by the ternary expression.

Comment: @ArtemSokolov You are right in that the compiler has enough information to figure out that both sides on the right of the ternary expression are constants, and both constants do fit in a `byte`. Together with the excluded middle principle this should give the compiler a way to not require a cast. However, implementing this functionality in a compiler is harder than requiring programmers to put an explicit cast, and is definitely easier for the compiler team (because they don't have to do anything :-)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Ok) Thanks for complete answer.